# GeoModel Usage in Google App Engine

Tags: python, google-app-engine, geolocation, google-cloud-datastore, geocoding

I am trying to do a proximity_fetch with the [GeoModel](https://developers.google.com/maps/articles/geospatial#wheretogo) class for Google App Engine.  The entity I want to use it for is ndb and I am not sure what I need to download and import and what I can just import from google in my python code.  The websites seem to be a little outdated and I was wondering if anyone had more pertinant information.  This is what I have so far and it is telling me that Location has no attribute proximity_fetch, which I know but I am not sure how I should define it in the Location(ndb.Model) class.

```
        g = geocoders.Google()

        place, (lat, lng) = g.geocode(inputlocation, exactly_one=False)


        bound = 20
        upper = lat + bound
        lower = lat - bound
        left = lng + bound
        right = lng - bound

        locations = []

        if lat and lng:
            locations = Location.proximity_fetch(
                                                 Location.query(),
                                                 geotypes.Point(lat, lng),
                                                 max_results=50,
                                                 max_distance=500000)
```

Also when I try to import geomodel and geotype which seem pretty vital for this it gives me an import error and I am not sure where to get them from.

Any help or examples would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should first checkout the latest code from the SVN repository. You can find the information about this at http://code.google.com/p/geomodel/source/checkout

After you have the code locally on your machine, inside the main directory there is a directory called `geo`. You should copy this directory into your GAE project. Then in your code, you import what you need from this package. For example:

```
from geo import geomodel
```

Now, regarding your `Location` model, in order to be able to execute a `proximity_fetch` Query, your model should extend the provided model in geomodel called `GeoModel`. Thus, you should have something like this:

```
class Location(ndb.Model, GeoModel):
....
```

Notice that `GeoModel` currently uses the "old" GAE datastore layer `db` and not `ndb` that you are using in your code. However, it shouldn't cause any trouble.

For more information on how to use geomodel, you should also take a look at the demos that also exist in the code you got from SVN. You can find them in the demos directory.

Hope this helps!

Comment: yes I have done all that and when I try to do Location(ndb.Model, GeoModel) I get:  metaclass conflict: the metaclass of a derived class must be a (non-strict) subclass of the metaclasses of all its bases google app engine

Comment: You are right, the reason for that is `GeoModel` already inherits from `db.Model`. Thus, your model that is inheriting indirectly from both `ndb.Model` and `db.Model`. There are two solutions to this situation. 
1) Modify your model to use only `db.Model`. In this case, you need only to inherit from `GeoModel`, i.e. `class Location(GeoModel)`. 
2) The other solution is to embed the `GeoModel` functionality into your class and modify it to use the `ndb` models and functions. What you will finally choose depends on your specific needs.

Comment: shouldn't it be relatively easy to change the GeoModel to ndb?  That is what I have done but I am still getting the same metaclass conflict error

Answer (score 1):

```
from geo import geotypes
```

They do a full example that can be found here: http://code.google.com/p/geomodel/source/browse/trunk/demos/pubschools/handlers/service.py
http://code.google.com/p/geomodel/source/browse/#svn/trunk/demos/pubschools

```
results = PublicSchool.proximity_fetch(
        base_query,
        center, max_results=max_results, max_distance=max_distance)
```

Comment: okay that works when I download it and import it but do you know how to get the proximity_fetch to work?